# software for managing ads on site

Tags: advertising

Could you recommend software to manage ads on a website? I'm talking about self managed banners, not adwords or anything like that. what are some of the commonly used ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has [their own solution](http://www.google.com/admanager/), although there are many different companies that provide their own solution (for example, [OpenX](http://www.openx.com/)).
I won't go into which ad manager is the best as that's not the idea of StackExchange QA - searching Google for companies that make ad managers or forum threads and blogs debating which is the best might be a good idea.

Comment: Google solution seems very interesting, thanks for sharing.